# Suggest a tool like Postman to connect using TCP/IP and send and receive messages on the same socket

Tags: sockets, tcp, postman, rest-client

I have written a program to create a persistent TCP/IP connection to a device and read unsolicited messages from the socket and also write message to the same socket and it is working fine.

I wanted to know is there a tool like Postman or Rest Client (We use this tool to test http rest endpoints) to open a persistent TCP/IP connection, which will use the same socket to send messages and also read unsolicited messages send through the same socket.

Please suggest if we have any tool like this, We want to use this tool to testing.

Comment: Any of the various netcat versions and clones; the telnet command line.